# Guice vs Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, guice

Someone said to me Guice is a better choice for a restful micro-services.

I said ...

Spring Boot offers:

```
- Core Spring Support - DI + AOP 
- Auto-Configuration: Web, Rest, Data, etc
- Activation Profiles: activate bits of code based on profiles 
- Simplified Web Development: code driven, no xml, no web.xml etc
- Web Testing Support: successful testing is easy testing
- Security Support: out of the box that can be customized
- JMS: out of the box support and can be excluded if not needed
- Actuator: health, trace, beans, info + much more etc 
- Executable and deployable WARs
- Natural fit for restful micro-services
- Fast loading
- extensible, native cloud support and much more
```

In a real web application these are the kind features that are needed during development and after deployment to production.

Guice-rs complain about older versions of Spring and that it’s slow to load and programmer error issues and so on and so forth.

From my readings Guice was created for super large applications that have many many developers working on them and in this case using something like Spring may take longer to load. Guice is a DI framework that gives you fine-grained control on how to load application code fast.

Now I haven’t used Guice and don’t know Guice yet, can someone form the Guice camp educate me on if/how can Guice provide the above features.

Many thanks!

Comment: You're comparing apples and bananas. Guice, at its core, is only a DI framework, just like Spring-core. So actually, you could as well be asking "which of spring-core or spring-boot is best for microservices?. So you see? Your question makes no sense!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wouldn't ask "which of spring-core or spring-boot is best for microservices?" in my view spring-boot is spring++ simple. The point I'm trying to make is that Guice offers less features than what is required on a commercial web project. Guice leaves a lot - in my limited view - up to the developer to provide, in exchange for fine-grained control as apposed to spring-boot's approach solving cross cutting concerns in a standard way which helps me to focus on the meat of the business logic. Thanks

Comment: Guice is only the DI framework. I don't know what you expect more.

Comment: Which is my point. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Context is the package that offers "Core Spring Support - DI + AOP" which you mentioned before. The other features in that list are provided by other spring packages. Spring boot wraps them all into a single bundle with auto-configuration.

TL;DR spring-context is similar to guice, guice by itself does not cover the other items on your list.